# How do I create clusters in dot?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Suppose, I want to make a subcluster between a few nodes in a graph (to somehow denote that these nodes go together for one reason or another for example):

```
digraph G {
  A [group=g1]
  {rank = same; B[group=g2]; C[group=g3]}
  D [group=g1]
  {rank = same; E[group=g2]; F[group=g3]}

  A -> B [label="2", weight=2]
  A -> C [label="0", style=dashed, weight=2]
  B -> C [label="0", style=dashed, weight=2]
  B -> D [label="2", style=dashed, weight=2]
  C -> D [label="0", weight=2]
  D -> E [label="1", style=dashed, weight=2]
  D -> F [label="0", weight=2]
  E -> F [label="0", weight=2]
  F -> A

  edge[style=invis];
  A -> D
  B -> E
  C -> F

  subgraph cluster_0 {
    label = "I want this in its own sub-square"
    B->E
    B->Asti

    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    node [style=filled,color=white];
    edge[style=invis];
  }

}
```

As you can see, I'm only partially successful. That is, `asti` is in its own greyed-out cluster but the nodes `B` and `E` are not.

Can someone please point out how do I place all three nodes `E`, `B` and `asti` in that greyed-out cluster?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `newrank=true` to avoid of "unboxing" clusters

```
digraph G {
  newrank=true;

  A [group=g1]
  {rank = same; B[group=g2]; C[group=g3]}
  D [group=g1]
  {rank = same; E[group=g2]; F[group=g3]}

  A -> B [label="2", weight=2]
  A -> C [label="0", style=dashed, weight=2]
  B -> C [label="0", style=dashed, weight=2]
  B -> D [label="2", style=dashed, weight=2]
  C -> D [label="0", weight=2]
  D -> E [label="1", style=dashed, weight=2]
  D -> F [label="0", weight=2]
  E -> F [label="0", weight=2]
  F -> A

  edge[style=invis];
  A -> D
  B -> E
  C -> F

  subgraph cluster_0 {
    label = "I want this in its own sub-square"
    B->E
    B->Asti

    style=filled;
    color=lightgrey;
    node [style=filled,color=white];
    edge[style=invis];
  }

}
```

[image]